# Unwanted allocations when enumerating tree

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am using Jetbrains rider with a C# project and using the Dynamic Program Analysis feature when debugging and I have piece of code which is showing issues with high memory allocation when enumerating a Tree Structure.

The tree needs to be thread safe as it can be written to by another thread while enumerated.

Here is the offending code that seems to be over allocating and, the JetBrains tool seems to think that the issue is due to a Closure Object but I am not convinced, it is on the small object heap

```
public IEnumerator<TreeNode<T>> GetEnumerator()
{
    yield return this;

    if (this.children == null)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    // Copy the children in case the collection gets modified while reading
    var childrenCopy = new List<TreeNode<T>>(this.children);

    foreach (var child in childrenCopy)
    {
        foreach (var subChild in child)
        {
            yield return subChild;
        }
    }
}
```

-- Update

I understand that the child copy will allocate, but once it's out of scope I would expect it to be released and not stuck on the small object heap

Any ideas on what is going would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "Seems to be allocating" you have a line that copies the list of children with an explicit comment that it's a copy. I'm not sure what the question is here? Are you looking for some other allocation? This will clone the entire tree if you run the enumerator to the end, that probably dominates the allocation footprint.

Comment: well, I'm guessing "Copy the children in case the collection gets modified while reading" is going to be the biggest cause of allocations... you can't get thread safety for free - you either need to use immutable structures, or you need to copy things *if* they're at risk - but at least with immutable structures you only pay for genuine changes, not for "just in case" scenarios

Comment: I understand that the child copy will allocate, but once it's out of scope I would expect it to be released and not stuck on the small object heap

Comment: @LennyD without seeing full context from the consuming side, it is impossible to comment; ultimately, this is what memory profilers are for - walk the roots, and see exactly how it is being held; we can't guess

Comment: @LennyD That depends on the usage. If you're doing a depth-first search with this enumerator then all the Lists of nodes on the path to the current node will be in scope. Depending on the shape of the tree that can be close to the entire tree being held as a copy.

Comment: Btw. this will only return the second level of the tree. Is this intended? Otherwise you will need either a recursive approach or a Stack<> based approach.

Comment: "I would expect it to be released and not stuck on the small object heap" Unless you call [`GC.Collect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect) yourself (which is discouraged), actual deallactions only happen if and when the GC decides it needs to run. Different .NET versions and/or runtime environments may have different thresholds before it will trigger. You could try [configuring the GC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/garbage-collector) but I have never tried it and don't know what can be achieved by that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The majority of allocations will be from the list copy. And this will not ensure thread safety as the list can be changed while you are doing the copy.

To fix this I would suggest using an immutable collection, like [`ImmutableList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1?view=net-7.0) for the children list. Adding a new node will create a new collection, i.e. `Children = Children.Add(newNode)`. This will increase allocations when adding items, but you will not need any defensive copies when iterating.

You will also do an allocation for each object in the tree, since the iterator block itself will require an allocation. If you want to fix this you can switch to an iterative instead of recursive approach. I.e. create a stack (or queue) that you loop over, popping an item and pushing all of its childs.

Answer (score 5):

The allocations are coming from the (failing) defensive copy:

```cs
// Copy the children in case the collection gets modified while reading
var childrenCopy = new List<TreeNode<T>>(this.children);
```

> The tree needs to be thread safe as it can be written to by another thread while enumerated.

Your code is already broken and doomed. If other threads are in play, they could change the data *even during that defensive copy operation*.

Comment: The allocations are coming from inside the house! (I'm sorry)